Transitioning push notifications using FCM from previous HTTP to HTTP v1
I use FCM. I read a notice from google, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=ja#c

For the transition from the previous HTTP to HTTP v1, an OAuth 2.0
access token is now required instead of a server key.

However, I am unsure how to obtain this token.
Current code
    func(){
        let serverKey:String = "AAAAA"
        let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
        let userIdToken:String = userIdToken
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)  
        
        let postMessage: [String: Any] = [
                "to": userIdToken,
                "priority": "high", 
                "content_available" : true, 
                "notification": [
                        "badge": 1,
                        "body": body,
                        "title": title
   ] as [String : Any]
  ]
  request.httpMethod = "POST"
  request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
  :
  :

The code I tried
    func(){
        //let serverKey:String = "AAAAA"
        //add
        let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/messages:send")!
        let userIdToken:String = userIdToken
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)   
        let postMessage: [String: Any] = [
                "to": userIdToken,
                "priority": "high", 
                "content_available" : true, 
                "notification": [
                        "badge": 1,
                        "body": body,
                        "title": title
                ] as [String : Any]
        ]

        /* I would like to know the solusion. */
        //add
        let accessToken:String = getOAuth2AccessToken()

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //add
        request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
  :
  :

I want to code this (getOAuth2AccessToken()) in Swift, but I'm not sure what to do.

Also: you really don't want to do this in your Swift code on an iOS device. Sending messages should only be done with a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. The reason for this is that anyone who can send messages to your app, can send any message they want to any of your users.

I am having same issue. I need to get oAuth2 access token at my iOS. did you find a way ?. I have serviceAcount json file from firebase. I can get Token for android, but not for iOS Thanks..
